# How to use EJS tags inside script tags in ejs files?

Tags: javascript, html, json, express, ejs

This is from YelpCamp, Colt Steele's course.  I am getting an error on this line of code in my index.ejs file.

```
const campgrounds = <%- JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>;
```

I tried this:

```
const campgrounds = '<%-JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>';
```

Then I use the console on Chrome, says campgrounds is not defined, even though I put campgrounds in the argument in the render() method in campgrounds.js (controller file).

```
module.exports.index = async (req, res) => { 
    const campgrounds = await Campground.find({}); 
    res.render('campgrounds/index', { campgrounds });
}
```

[image]

If there's not enough information, let me know so I can edit the OP.  Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the error.
Just use:

```
const campgrounds = <%- JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>;
```